# Call Dialog from CPP (c++) file to QML in QT Mobile (iOS and Android)

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, qml, cross-platform

QML code:

```
Dialog {
    id: dialog
    objectName: dialog
    modal: true
    standardButtons: Dialog.cancel | Dialog.Ok

    title: qsTr("About")

    Label {
        text: "Lorem ipsum..."
    }
}
```

CPP

```
void LoginPage::checkLogin(QString username, QString password)
{
    if(username == "username" && password == "password")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        QObject *rect = findChild<QObject*>("dialog");
        //this solution don't work
    }
}
```

I need to call dialog from cpp, I searched online but I not found solutions.
My target is open Dialog error from cpp file.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Sure, you are trying to search child of `LoginPage` instance. You should get root item of QML tree and so search through its children.

Comment: Secondly, I think you should put the `objectName` between quotes in qml: `objectName: "dialog"`

Comment: Why not use signals and slots? Maybe emit a signal like loginFailed() in the C++ side. then inside QML you can use Connections { target: loginPage; onLoginFailed: console.log("Meh") }.

Answer (score 0):

Available approaches are very well described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html). The closest version to what you are asking is you have to have a root object and `findChild` with `objectName` that set in QML declaration. After you get it, modify properties that you would like, e.g. `visible` and etc.

But that does not look like a clean approach, because you have to have the root element, you have to pre-create the dialog and hide it.

I would suggest to register [a context property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) with some member properties and change this properties to trigger QML logic, e.g. showing the diaglog or not.

Even more cleaner approach that might be applicable for you is to do validation directly in QML.

Comment: I did see your link, but I don't call the objet like method in the link, I can't include library in cpp

Comment: What do you meant to include library in cpp? Basically, you have to have an access to the root component in order to modify any properties and/or call function on its children.